# How to compare 2 oracle schema script files?

Tags: oracle, database-schema

Given 2 Oracle schemas script files, can I *objectically* compare them ***without*** real schemes which are created and live on an Oracle server?

I'm looking for a way to compare 2 schemas script files and in return to recieve a synchronization-script without really creating them on an Oracle Server.

I thought of creating a temporary in-memory schemas at run-time for that task but it would maybe be an overkill and I'd like to see your suggestions.

Is it possible? There some known tools for that task?

**Update:** It's important to note that I'm not looking for a text-diff, but rather to schema objects (tables, columns, procedures etc ) compration.

Comment: Anything's possible, but you'd have to work out how to parse the scripts into an object model, I guess, and compare and interpret the differences into create, alter and drop statements. Since they would have to be Oracle-specific I would have thought any existing tools (like SQL Developer's schema comparison wizard) would be based on a DB schema rather than a flat file, which might have variable formatting to deal with etc. Is running the scripts into two schemas really such a problem?

Comment: @AlexPoole I want to create an automatic tool which in few clicks will provide me with a sync-script.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using the tool WinMerge for this tasks. With that tool you can compare two text files and it will show you the differences in these files. But the merge process have to be done manually(I have to say that my files aren't as big), but I haven't found a good tool for do this so far.

Best wishes

Comment: I'm not looking for a text diff, but rather to schema objects (tables, columns etc.) diff,

Comment: You were talking about script files. And these are actually text files in my mind, so I missunderstood this question sorry.

Comment: I think tools such as the SyBase PowerDesigner are able to import schema files and generate the diff of them. But I guess you are searching for an opensource product. I acctually dont know any opensource project which have this functionality